# Method waits for a thread's termination

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been stuck on this academic exercise. I know it's very simple, but I can't get a grasp on.

This is the assignment:

> Create a method that accepts a Thread t, and a k number. This method
> waits until t's termination up to k seconds. It returns true if t
> terminated in the meantime, otherwise it returns false if the timeout
> is up.

This is what I tried:

```
public static boolean myJoin(Thread t, int k){


    boolean flag = true;
    
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                t.join();
                }
             catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    }
        }
    };

            t1.start();
            try {
                t1.sleep(k);
                flag = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e){   
            }
            t1.interrupt();
            
            
            return flag;
}
```

Comment: "This is what i tried:" did it work? What did it do wrong?

Comment: Have you thought that maybe the code would be as simple as calling `join(k * 1000L)`?

Comment: *FYI:* `k` is in *seconds*. `sleep()` argument is in **milliseconds**.

Comment: Re, `t1.sleep(k);` I think that statement does not do what you think it does. Hint: It doesn't do _anything_ to the `t1` thread. `sleep(...)` is a _class method_. One of the idiosyncrasies of Java is that it allows you to call a class method using the syntax of an _instance method_ call, even though the class method does not do anything to the given instance.

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware sleep's argument is in milliseconds, but i forgot. Thank you for reminding me. I totally missed the fact that sleep is a Class Method. However, my main problem is that i don't understand the logic i have to follow, hence why i didn't write anything about what did it do. I studied how thread works, i have all the ingredients, but it seems i can't put them together.

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread. It seems completely unnecessary. [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) with a timeout is really all you need.

Comment: public static boolean myJoin(Thread t, int k) throws InterruptedException {
  t.join(k * 1_000);
  return t.isAlive();
}

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why cant you use [Thread::join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) which is what you are trying to accomplish.

That being said if you are trying to implement a method that is roughly the same as that, why not model your solution after the standard JDK definition of that method? i.e. [Thread.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1233)

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

where [isAlive](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/11/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()) and [wait](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/11/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) are both public methods on Thread, so you can pass a thread in and use the methods associated with that instance.